# Twilio - who said what

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am following this blog https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/introducing-dual-channel-recording.html and was able to get recording for each channel. How to differentiate who said what using following response ?

```
{
    "first_page_uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f/Calls/CAfc653524fde406f6ebeb105d8865cc9c/Recordings.json?PageSize=50&Page=0",
    "end": 5,
    "previous_page_uri": null,
    "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f/Calls/CAfc653524fde406f6ebeb105d8865cc9c/Recordings.json?PageSize=50&Page=0",
    "page_size": 50,
    "start": 0,
    "recordings": [
        {
            "sid": "RE014948146c2838667c4ee2296e2f8dab",
            "account_sid": "ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f",
            "call_sid": "CAfc653524fde406f6ebeb105d8865cc9c",
            "duration": "1",
            "date_created": "Wed, 04 Oct 2017 16:37:00 +0000",
            "api_version": "2010-04-01",
            "date_updated": "Wed, 04 Oct 2017 16:37:01 +0000",
            "status": "completed",
            "source": "RecordVerb",
            "channels": 1,
            "price": "-0.00250",
            "price_unit": "USD",
            "encryption_details": null,
            "error_code": null,
            "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f/Recordings/RE014948146c2838667c4ee2296e2f8dab.json"
        },
        {
            "sid": "RE1ac589e42f05c8370d74e04d7480bea7",
            "account_sid": "ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f",
            "call_sid": "CAfc653524fde406f6ebeb105d8865cc9c",
            "duration": "18",
            "date_created": "Wed, 04 Oct 2017 16:36:37 +0000",
            "api_version": "2010-04-01",
            "date_updated": "Wed, 04 Oct 2017 16:37:01 +0000",
            "status": "completed",
            "source": "RecordVerb",
            "channels": 1,
            "price": "-0.00250",
            "price_unit": "USD",
            "encryption_details": null,
            "error_code": null,
            "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd6b6b7dc8ae6f3e6f7ff72c8dbbd457f/Recordings/RE1ac589e42f05c8370d74e04d7480bea7.json"
        }
    ],
    "next_page_uri": null,
    "page": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

> For the dual-channel options, you can choose record-from-answer-dual
>   or record-from-ringing-dual. The parent call will always be in the
>   first channel and the child call will always be in the second channel.

Having said that your response is indicating that your recordings are single channel, which isn't what I would expect but I've never used dual channel recording so I don't know for sure. Your timestamps don't overlap though, so I suspect these are not individual channels from the same call.

Comment: Are you sure or unsure with your comment.

Comment: I'm fairly sure, but I'm just some guy with a Twilio t-shirt, not a Twilio guru. I've no doubt one will see this and confirm pretty soon though. In the meantime if you share the code you are using to set up the calls that should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Both of those recordings say that they were made using the `RecordVerb`. That is [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record). Recordings made with `<Record>` can only record one stream of audio, it is normally used in a call with just one leg as part of a voicemail system.

The only way you can make dual channel recordings is if you [generate a call from the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls) and connect it to one other user with [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) and [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number) or [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client) or [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) or [`<Sim>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sim).

You cannot get dual, or more, channel recordings of a Conference with Twilio yet.